# How to force Github Pages to look at /build?

Tags: html, reactjs, github, deployment

I'm using create-react-app which is serving its files from the /build folder. Typically Github Pages looks at index.html at the root level, but I'd like to direct it to look at /build for deployment.

I've tried to add `"homepage": "/build"` inside my package.json configuration, and Github Settings says it's deployed via `<username>.github.io`. However, the site just shows my README.md file.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Have you checked the "deploy to github pages" section at https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md ? there's a detailed step-by-step guide on how to do that, and you don't need to try fiddling with github pages.

Comment: Yeah, I've read this but it only tells how to build it for gh-pages, which is a Project Page with the url `<username>.github.io/<repository_name>`, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that this is a Web Browser issue, and not a Host issue. When you visit a webpage your browser always looks for the `index.html` file at the URL so `localhost:8080` becomes `localhost:8080/index.html`.

This means that there are a couple ways to fix this. You could create an `index.html` file in your root directory and then have that serve up the scripts in the build folder like `<script src="build/main.js"></script>`

You could also go through the pain and suffering of manually adding `/build` to the end of the URL. But you don't want users to have to do that, so you could write a script to redirect you there.

Good luck!

Comment: Is that the only way to serve up the website? I can't make Github look at my build folder instead? :(